# How To Stop json_enocde To Encode Unicode?

Tags: php, json

I'm doing following PHP code on server:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

// HELL LOT OF CODE

$array = array($url => $link, 'Made With ♥');

echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Expected: "Made With ♥"
Actual: "Made With \u2665"

Any guesses programmers?

Thanks! Everyone upvoted! Cheers! Fastest Answer won the correct one! :D

Comment: See the ‘options’ section of the [the documentation](http://php.net/%20json_encode)... You could have figured this out youself :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need at least PHP 5.4

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

*JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE (integer)
Encode multibyte Unicode characters literally (default is to escape as \uXXXX). Available since PHP 5.4.0.*

Comment: It should be `json_encode($var, 'u2665');` Right? But it returns me error `json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given`

Comment: @user2513722 No, it should be exactly what he posted :p

Comment: @user2513722 no, just use `echo json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

Comment: But it gives me output now as: `Made With â™¥` What the heck? @mochalygin

Comment: @user2513722 do you use the same charsets on all pages? `header('Content-Type: application/json');` this header sets `charset` to `UTF8`

Comment: I'm using this as an api. This is a json api which returns json response.

Comment: Yeah setting `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` as suggested by @Ghost worked.

Comment: Try change header of json page next way: `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the optional flag `JSON_UNESCAPE_UNICODE` (PHP 5.4 or above) for this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
exit;
```

Comment: i don't know whats the reason, there is nothing wrong with that

Comment: It gives me output as `Made With â™¥` What's the problem now?

Comment: @user2513722 always set to utf-8

Answer (score 1):

You need : `json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`